# How do I repeat an image in a table on the x axis with html?

Tags: html, css, image

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<img src="Nintendo.full.2534139.JPG" />
</tr>
<td>
<h1>Random text blah blah</h1>
</td>
```

This is my code that I used. I've tried `Background-repeat: repeat-x;` but that didn't work so could someone help me with this?

Comment: you need to consider background-image not the the img element

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put the `background-repeat: repeat-x;` ?

Did you target your table tag in CSS?

```
table {
  background-image: url(your-img-url);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Or you could try wrapping everything on a div, and adding a class such as `class="bg-img"` to that div.

And instead of using table, you'll do something like this into your CSS

```
.bg-img {
      background-image: url(your-img-url);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
```